# False resource leak warning?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings, java-7, try-with-resources

I'm getting a resource leak warnings on 's' and 'p' in this snippet.  Is this warning valid?

```
try (StringWriter s = new StringWriter(); PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(s)) {
    p.print(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
    p.print('/');
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface i = e.nextElement();
        System.out.println(i);
        if (i.getHardwareAddress() == null || i.getHardwareAddress().length == 0)
            continue;
        for (byte b : i.getHardwareAddress())
            p.printf("%02x", b);
        return s.toString();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to determine Host ID");
}
```

Comment: Maybe an error in Eclipse' compiler? Try throwing the exception outside the try block

Comment: That's what I'm suspecting as well, but try-with-resources is still a bit new to me so I wanted to triple check.

Comment: Maybe you can open your code in Netbeans or IntelliJ IDEA as well and check what they say.

Comment: What IDE you are using? With Eclipse Juno Service Release 2, there is NO warnings.

Comment: Voting to close as this was likely an Eclipse bug that has since been fixed - I also see no such warning in modern Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet - no. There are no resources to speak of, other than those managed by the JVM.